# Trying to Understand Least Upper Bound Example

Tags: scala

Given the following trait and 2 sub-classes:

```
scala> trait Parent
defined trait Parent

scala> case object Kid extends Parent
defined object Kid

scala> case object Child extends Parent
defined object Child
```

I created a function that returns either a `Kid` or a `Child`. But the inferred return type is `Product with Serializable with Parent`.

```
scala> def f(x: Int) = if (true) Kid else Child
f: (x: Int)Product with Serializable with Parent
```

Then, I re-write the same function, except that I explicitly annotate its type:

```
scala> def g(x: Int): Parent = if (true) Kid else Child
g: (x: Int)Parent
```

Please explain `f`'s inferred type.

Answer (score 6):

Case objects always inherit from both `Product` and `Serializable` (this is transparently done by the compiler).

In addition here both `Kid` and `Child` explicitly extend `Parent`

So both `Kid` and `Child` are subtypes of `Product with Serializable with Parent`.
Because they have no further common types, this is their least upper bound.

Comment: Why didn't the compiler resolve the LUB to be `Parent` alone?

Comment: Because "Least Upper Bound" basically means "the most specific common type". Both `Kid` and `Child` are sub-types of `Product with Serializable with Parent`, and `Product with Serializable with Parent` is more specific (is a sub-type) of `Parent`