# Shouldn’t `EitherT` be covariant? Especially in the Left?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats

I have the following code

```
def addKitten(kitten: Kitten): EitherT[Future, GenericError, UUID] = {
  val futureOfEither = db.run { // returns a Future[Int] with the number of rows written
    kittens += kitten
  }.map {
    case 1 => kitten.uuid.asRight
    case _ => GenericError.SpecificError.asLeft
  }
  EitherT(futureOfEither)
}
```

Where `SpecificError` is a subclass of `GenericError`. For some reason it does not compile complaining that a `SpecificError` is not a `GenericError`. Is it right?

I mean, `Either[A, B]` should be immutable, so why not making it covariant? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same issue for `XorT` and `OptionT` was raised [here](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/issues/556). The reply was:

> In Scala, variance has both positives and negatives (perhaps that's how they decided on variance notation! :P). These pros/cons have been discussed numerous times in various venues, so I won't go into them now, but in my opinion at the end of the day you kind of have to settle on "to each their own".
>
> I think this "to each their own" perspective implies that you can't force variance on a type constructor. A concrete example is `scalaz.Free` in the 7.0 series. It forces the `S` type constructor to be covariant. At the time I often wanted to wrap a `Coyoneda` in `Free`. The most recent versions of Cats and Scalaz have the `Coyoneda` essentially built into the `Free`, so this particular use might not be as desired now, but the general principle applies. The problem is that `Coyoneda` is invariant, so you simply couldn't do this (without a mess of `@uncheckedVariance`)! By making type constructor parameters invariant, you may end up forcing people to be more explicit about types, but I think that it beats the alternative, where you can prevent them from being able to use your type at all.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found a workaround.

I still have no idea why the `EitherT` is not covariant but you have to remember that the `Either` itself *is* covariant.
So the trick is to tell the compiler to use an upper bound for the `EitherT` creation:

```
EitherT[Future, GenericError, UUID](futureOfEither)
```

Having more than one error as left works too (because the compiler is forced to find the LUB) *but* `GenericError` has to extend `Product` and `Serializable` if it’s a trait and `SpecificError` is a case class (refer to [this question as to why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30849044/trying-to-understand-least-upper-bound-example))

```
...
}.map {
  case 1 => kitten.uuid.asRight
  case 2 => GenericError.SpecificError2.asLeft
  case _ => GenericError.SpecificError.asLeft
}
EitherT(futureOfEither)
```

Comment: In Scala Future already wraps a `scala.util.Try` that can be either `Error` or something, I'm not sure why `Future[Either]` is sometimes chosen, but it brings no benefit whatsoever other than more CPU cycles and runtime complexity.

Comment: @flavian Try's "failure" is always an unspecific "Throwable" where as "Future[Either]" lets you add a type constraint for the error.  You can move application-specific errors into "Either" and leave "Future.failed" for fatal infrastructure errors and thus achieve a clear separation between fatal and expected errors.

Comment: You can already do that with `Exception` and `Throwable`, so it's still just boilerplate. Scala also gives you `scala.util.control.NonFatal`.

Answer (score 0):

As another quite neat workaround you could specify abstract types in `flatMap[E, T]` type parameters, for example:

```
// Given ADT
trait Err
case class E1() extends Err
case class E2() extends Err
// We could do (pseudo-code)
EitherT(E1()).flatMap[Err, Int] { x => 100 }
```

It is in case of `FlatMap`. For `Map` you could only transform value and type on the right side.